# Ruby on Rails: Use form_for on a model, and flip the form value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-for

I've got a form_for form, and within it, I'm using a form helper check box. The model has a field that's a boolean value, but I'd like to be able to display it on my form in terms of its converse since I think that's easier for users to understand.

**Is there any way for me to have a Rails form helper act as if the model's boolean field is flipped?**

Example:

```
<% form_for :user do |form| %>
  <%= form.check_box :privacy_disabled %>
<% end %>
```

In this example, the User model has a boolean field `privacy_disabled`. I would like to display this in the form as check here to *enable* privacy.

The checkbox helper function has the ability to set its checked and unchecked values, but inverting these does not seem to properly populate the checkbox with the pre-saved value.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is how I ended up solving this issue, I was actually close with my first attempt:

```
<%= form.check_box :privacy_disabled, 
                   {:checked => !@user.privacy_disabled}, 
                   0,
                   1 %>
```

So the values returned by the checkbox are flipped, and whether it starts out checked is manually flipped as well.

Answer (score 6):

Not the most elegant solution, but you could do something like the following:

1. Add these methods to your user model:

   ```
   def privacy_enabled=(val)
     self.privacy_disabled = val == "0"
   end
   def privacy_enabled
     !privacy_disabled
   end
   ```
2. Change the form to:

   ```
   <%= form.check_box :privacy_enabled %>
   ```

Again, not elegant, but it works.

Comment: This is a fine solution; it's easy to read and understand on all sides, and it can be easily moved into some view-specific code when the need arises.